# Should we keep the [aquarium] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [aquarium](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium) tag is used on only two question. It may be overly specific. The best tags offer value beyond a simple keyword search, and in this case both questions already include the keyword in their titles. It's also unclear whether aquariums have any connection to sustainability in the general sense.

Do we want to keep or remove this tag?

Answer (score 2):

Since we've already got [fish](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish), [aquaponics](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquaponics), I think it's safe to remove this one. Those two questions weren't about aquaponics, but with [fish](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish) they'd be easy to find.